# Numerical methods for finding an eigen basis of a degenerate Liouvillian

Tags: programming, density-matrix, qutip

I'm trying to find the steady-state of a master equation,
$$\dot{\rho}(t) = \mathcal{L}\rho(t),\tag{1}\label{1}$$
In the form where we vectorise the density matrix and matrixify (??) the Liouvillian super operator $\rho$ is a vector representing a state, $\mathcal{L}$ is the Liouvillian, a complex matrix describing the evolution, which is not necessarily symmetric and $\dot{\rho}$ is the rate of change of $\rho$. To find the steady-state we need to set the LHS of the equation to 0 and solve for $\rho$.
This is just the eigenvector problem, $(\mathcal{L}-\lambda\pmb{I})\rho=0$ for the case where the eigenvalue, $\lambda=0$.

In many systems I am studying the 0 eigenvalue of $\mathcal{L}$ is degenerate so there should be more than one solution for the original master equation. Ideally, we could find a basis for the degenerate subspace (I assume that this subspace of $\mathcal{L}$ is diagonalizable). Qutip has the function `steadystate()` which, given a system Hamiltonian and some jump operators uses various numerical methods to find the steadystate. I am relatively new to using numerical methods but the systems I am dealing with are large so requires it. I have tried using the GMRES method to solve equation \eqref{1} with $\dot{\rho}=0$ but this only produces a single solution and does not help me find a basis.

An alternative approach is to use the function `liouvillian()` which given the same parameters as `steadystate()` returns the Liouvillian, `L`, of the system in matrix form. We can then use `L.eigenstate()` to find the eigenvectors associated with the zero eigenvalues. A few issues with this is that the zero eigenvalues are never quite zero but just very small, however I'm not sure this is necessarily a problem. The eigenvectors produced appear to be linearly independent, at least in the simple case I'm looking at where the system is only doubly degenerate in the zero eigenvalue, so they could form a basis for this degenerate subspace. Finally, when the Liouvillian is applied to any linear combination of these eigenvectors (as long as the cofactors are not too large) the result is zero. My only problem is that when I apply the Liouvillian to the steadystate produced by the GMRES approach the result is not zero and after some simple checks it does not appear to be in the space spanned by the eigenvectors. Is this necessarily a problem or just an issue of numerical accuracy. Is my approach of using the eigenvectors of the zero eigenvalue as a basis for the steadystate valid?

Any advice on solving this problem would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Presumably, you're actually interested in all eigenvalues for which the real component is 0 (if the subspace is degenerate, chances are a Hamiltonian could create evolution within that subspace, described by imaginary eigenvalues). I don't know if this has any relevance to the particular problem you're looking at?

Comment: Yes! I'm also interested in imaginary eigenvalues but I thought I would leave that for another question if this thread gives some insightful answers. However, I think these eigenvalues will be easier to deal with as they tend not to be degenerate. I've only just begun to explore these types of systems so perhaps I may come across purely imaginary degenerate eigenvalues in the future... if it's possible for them to exist.

Comment: It could be that the steadystate found by the function ```steadystate()``` is not part of the space spanned by the two degenerate eigenvalues because it also has a component in the space of purely imaginary eigenvalues but I've checked and the specific system I'm looking at has no purely imaginary eigenvalues. All other eigenvalues have a negative real part, except the two degenerate zero eigenvalues.